# Connections between topos theory and geometric group theory?

Tags: reference-request, geometric-group-theory, topos-theory

In the spirit of [Ronnie brown's answer to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154395/connections-of-geometric-group-theory-with-other-areas-of-mathematics), I was wondering whether there are any connections between topos theory and geometric group theory.

The question might seem strange, but it is motivated by some references about Sheaves on Graphs I have been told about. Since I know very few things about this, I was trying to understand whether there are connections with fields, as geometric group theory, which are more familiar to me.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion; I hope that you will forgive me for the somehow strange kind of the question.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, topoi have no connection to mathematics outside of algebraic geometry and logic. In contrast, sheaves (on topological spaces) are a standard tool in complex analysis, general and algebraic topology (as well as algebraic geometry, of course). I know only of one application of sheaves on graphs to geometric group theory.

Comment: An example of applications of toposes in applied mathematics that I particularly like is [temporal type theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10258). If I remember Spivak's talk at the Como topos event correctly, they applied this in the real world, that is, at a company.